# Как вызвать функцию при изменении объекта?

Tags: ооп, javascript, mvc

Есть, допустим, объект

```
obj={name:'value'};
```

Как вызывать функцию  каждый раз при изменении объекта (добавлении нового свойства, удаления свойства), и каждый раз при чтении свойства (допустим, другую функцию)?
Геттеры и сеттеры, видимо, здесь не сработают.

Comment: Если это storage - тогда там есть нативные методы. Если это свой объект - тогда через свои get и set, а также bind и unbind (для функций), расширив базовый набор свойств Object. И соответственно, обращаться к объекту только через установленные свойства.



Comment: без обверток - никак

Answer (score 3, accepted):

существует НЕ кросбраузерный метод: [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

```
function onFooChange( id, oldval, newval ) {

  console.log( id + " property changed from " + oldval + " to " + newval );
  return newval;
}

var o = { foo:5 };
o.watch( 'foo', onFooChange );

o.foo = 6; // foo property changed from 5 to 6

delete o.foo;

o.foo = 7; //foo property changed from undefined to 7

o.unwatch('foo');
o.foo = 8;
```

Comment: Очень круто.что-то не могу найти поддержку по браузерам.
Вот здесь  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029241/javascript-object-watch-for-all-browsers автор Eli Grey говорит о кроссе It works in IE8, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.У меня в IE8 не сработало.Что скажеш?

Comment: возможно он заблуждается

Comment: эмм,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

****

>**Warning**: Generally you should avoid using watch() and unwatch() when possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're intended primarily for debugging use. In addition, using watchpoints has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true when used on global objects, such as window. You can usually use setters and getters or proxies instead. See Compatibility for details.

Comment: Ценная инфа  AlexWindHope .СПС

Comment: ну да, эта ценная инфа идёт первой и единственной ссылкой в ответе=)

Comment: @Spectre я это увидел, странно то, что вы не почитали дальше и не дошли до 'use setters and getters or proxies instead', как я понимаю человек спрашивал для реального применения, watch, по понятным причинам, для этих целей не подходил (если речь не об отладке, тут, порой, действительно удобно)

Comment: да именно для практических целей.

Comment: >либо, по неясным для меня причинам, не сочли нужным об этом упомянуть

да, вы правы, нужно было, не упомянул потому-что ответ изначально должен был быть просто комментом